# Firefox does not scale images inside flexbox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, cross-browser, scale

Edit: Here is a codepen and a screenshot showcasing the issue

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mitsest/pen/qJaeaz)

[image: different rendering on browsers]

I 'm trying to center align an image using flexbox, maintain its aspect ratio, and also have transparent background below it (check images below).
I approached the problem by creating a full-height-width parent container, containing 4 rows (first is title, second is logo, third are social links, fourth is a chevron-down-icon)
So parent container has flex-direction: row containing these 4.
Inside the logo container I have a parent column container with flex-direction: column, containing 2 empty divs with flex: 1 and my app logo.

### Mixins

```
=full-height-width
  width: 100%
  height: 100%

=fill($background-color: null)
  flex: 1
  display: flex
  height: 100%

=flex-center-contents
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center

// grid mixins
=row($z-index: auto)
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  z-index: $z-index
  flex-wrap: nowrap

=column($z-index: auto)
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  z-index: $z-index
  flex-wrap: nowrap
```

### Styles

```
// Grid implementation
.fill
  +fill($logo-background-color)
  z-index: $not-animated-background-z-index

.parent-row-container
  +full-height-width()
  +row($not-animated-background-z-index)

.parent-column-container
  +full-height-width()
  +column($not-animated-background-z-index)
#parent-container
  +full-height-width()
  #social-container, #name-container, #logo-container
    flex: 1

  #social-container, #name-container
    background-color: $logo-background-color
    +flex-center-contents()
    z-index: $not-animated-background-z-index

  #name-container
    > #name
      color: $home-primary-text-color
      font-family: $font-stack-sci-fi
      font-size: $name-font-size

      text-align: center
      user-select: none

  #logo-container
    display: flex

    > #logo-img-wrapper

      > #logo
        max-height: 100%
        max-width: 100%
        object-fit: contain

  #social-container
    display: flex
    flex-wrap: wrap

    > .social-icon
      font-size: $social-icon-font-size

      min-width: 85px
      +media("<=tablet")
        min-width: 45px

      text-align: center


  #bottom-arrow-container
    background-color: $logo-background-color
    padding-bottom: 1rem
    +flex-center-contents()
    z-index: $not-animated-background-z-index
```

### Html

```
<div class="parent-row-container">
  <!-- Row -->
  <div class id="name-container">
    <p id="name">
      Artist name
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- End Row -->

  <!-- Row -->
  <div id="logo-container" class="parent-column-container">
    <!-- Column -->
    <div class="fill"></div>
    <!-- Column -->
    <div id="logo-img-wrapper">
      <img id="logo" src="@img/home/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <!-- Column -->
    <div class="fill"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Row -->

  <!-- Row -->
  <div class="fill">
    <!-- Column -->
    <div id="social-container">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-arrow-container">
    <font-awesome-icon class="selectable" :icon="['fa', 'chevron-down']" :style="{ color: 'white'}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in the following when run on Chromium/opera (expected)
[image]

But firefox produces this
[image]

Has this something to do with how firefox treats percentage widths?
If i amend the img container and put flex: 1 on the image container firefox is fixed, but chromium/opera break, and they center the image (because of object-fit: contain) leaving spaces at the edges (also expected behavior) Also, if I remove completely the img from the html, the grid is the same as with chrome/opera

[image]

Have any of you experienced anything similar?

Comment: Maybe you just need to make your style **css**  compatible  with other browser using [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: I thought vue-cli already uses autoprefixer. I might be wrong as there is no indication that it does (by a quick grep), though the exported css does have some attributes prefixed (see on my second screenshot -o-object-fit)

Comment: try this : take your exported **css** and autoprefixe it [here](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) then we will fetch for another solution !! or maybe your **Firefox** it not updated

Comment: [This image](https://picsum.photos/200/300) is rendering differently in Chrome and Firefox. Is this some kind of magic?

Comment: @rv7 My thoughts exactly!!

Comment: What OS and browser versions are you using?

Comment: @wiiiiilllllll
This is latest Chrome / Firefox ESR / Opera on Debian 9

Comment: @mitsest Thanks. Maybe the fact you're on Debian is significant? I can't replicate the issue in latest Chrome or latest Firefox, on Windows 7

Comment: @wiiiiilllllll

Just tried on windows and unfortunately the issue persists. I uploaded an image at the top of the question.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you use oddly complex approach (using extra empty columns, `object-contain` and hard way). Here I've just used `align-items`,`text-align` and `justify-content` in one or two cases, and problem is solved:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOOZqb

Comment: The extra complexity comes from the following requirement:

Having an animated backround below the image, which is visible only at the parts where the logo is transparent.

Thanks for your answer, I 'll have a look!

Comment: Check the screenshots and notice the background below the logo.

Comment: @mitsest ah, i didnt know that, as this example is not real one of your work. ok, you can use the same html (instead of mine example) but accomodate the css parts, might help.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox not working anymore after firefox `34.0.5` but you get it to fix by a CSS trick as:

**This worked for me:**

```
img {max-width:100%; width:100%;}
```

Comment: I 'll try it when I get back home, and if it fixes the issue, the bounty is yours!

Thanks for your time :)